# Highlight line in RichEditControl

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I try to highlight a specifiable line of a `RichEditControl` of DevExpress.
[Here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E4435) is a sample that uses selection. I don't want to select the line to highlight and I don't have any idea how to calculate the range of a line. The only information I have is the line number to select. There is [another](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3487) sample that uses the CaretPosition to select the line.

Both samples are working perfect but I don't know how to set the selection or CaretPositon by line number.

How can I calculate the DocumentPosition or range of a single line to use the samples to highlight it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "line number". I think RTF is paragraph-based, and thus the line number can change if you change the margins of the page it is formatted onto, can't it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5890

*related with formatting of Text .*